# Show padding zeros using DecimalFormat

Tags: java, formatting, decimalformat

I'm using DecimalFormat to format doubles to 2 decimal places like this:

```
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double rawPercent = ( (double)(count.getCount().intValue()) / 
                            (double)(total.intValue()) ) * 100.00;
double percentage = Double.valueOf(dec.format(rawPercent));
```

It works, but if i have a number like 20, it gives me this:

```
20.0
```

and I want this:

```
20.00
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The DecimalFormat class is for transforming a decimal numeric value into a String.  In your example, you are taking the String that comes from the format( ) method and putting it back into a double variable.  If you are then outputting that double variable you would not see the formatted string.  See the code example below and its output:

```
int count = 10;
int total = 20;
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
double rawPercent = ( (double)(count) / (double)(total) ) * 100.00;

double percentage = Double.valueOf(dec.format(rawPercent));

System.out.println("DF Version: " + dec.format(rawPercent));
System.out.println("double version: " + percentage);
```

Which outputs:

```
"DF Version: 50.00"
"double version: 50.0"
```

Answer (score 20):

Try this code:

```
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal("100.25");

BigDecimal decimal2 = new BigDecimal("1000.70");

BigDecimal decimal3 = new BigDecimal("10000.00");

DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,###.##");

format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);

format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

System.out.println(format.format(decimal));

System.out.println(format.format(decimal2));

System.out.println(format.format(decimal3));
```

Result:

```
100.25

1,000.70

10,000.00
```

Comment: How does your answer add anything to the question? The question has been answered 4 years ago and apparently to the satisfaction of the OP. Also: please use the provided formatting facilities to format your code.

Comment: This answer helped me, as I used `format.setMinimumFractionDigits()`. While not the same as the OP's case, in my case, I needed to change the number of decimal places depending on other factors, so this allowed me to keep a single overall pattern, but vary the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 8):

You can try something like:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000000");
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
df.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
```

This way you can ensure the minimum number of digits before or after the decimal

Answer (score 7):

Use format "#.00".

Comment: You haven't showed us your print statement. If you do dec.format(percentage), the format will work.

Comment: It is better to use "0.00" as "#.00" would format 0 as .00 which doesn't look good in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

I found my small test program useful and want to share it with you. Enjoy.

```
package be.softwarelab.numbers;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DecimalNumbers {

    private static final double ZERO = 0;
    private static final double TEN = 10.0;
    private static final double PI = Math.PI;                           // 3.141592653589793;
    private static final double MILLIONS = Math.E * Math.pow(10, 6);    // 2718281.828459045;
    private static final double NINERS = 9999999.99999;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String format01 = "#.#";
        String format02 = "0.#";
        String format03 = "#.0";
        String format04 = "0.0";
        String format05 = "##.#";
        String format06 = "00.#";

        String formatAll = "###,###.###";
        String formatLong = "#.#########";  

        System.out.println("====== ZERO =================================================");
        showResult(ZERO, format01, Locale.US);
        showResult(ZERO, format02, Locale.US);
        showResult(ZERO, format03, Locale.US);
        showResult(ZERO, format04, Locale.US);
        showResult(ZERO, format05, Locale.US);
        showResult(ZERO, format06, Locale.US);
        System.out.println("====== TEN  =================================================");
        showResult(TEN, format01, Locale.US);
        showResult(TEN, format02, Locale.US);
        showResult(TEN, format03, Locale.US);
        showResult(TEN, format04, Locale.US);
        showResult(TEN, format05, Locale.US);
        showResult(TEN, format06, Locale.US);
        System.out.println("====== PI   =================================================");
        showResult(PI, format01, Locale.US);
        showResult(PI, format02, Locale.US);
        showResult(PI, format03, Locale.US);
        showResult(PI, format04, Locale.US);
        showResult(PI, format05, Locale.US);
        showResult(PI, format06, Locale.US);
        System.out.println("====== MILLIONS =============================================");
        showResult(MILLIONS, formatAll, Locale.US);
        showResult(MILLIONS, formatAll, Locale.GERMANY);
        showResult(MILLIONS, formatAll, Locale.FRANCE);
        showResult(MILLIONS, formatAll, new Locale("nl", "BE"));
        System.out.println("====== NINERS   =============================================");
        showResult(NINERS, format01, Locale.US);
        showResult(NINERS, format02, Locale.US);
        showResult(NINERS, format03, Locale.US);
        showResult(NINERS, format04, Locale.US);
        showResult(NINERS, format05, Locale.US);
        showResult(NINERS, format06, Locale.US);
        showResult(NINERS, formatLong, Locale.US);
        System.out.println("=============================================================");
    }

    public static void showResult(double number, String format, Locale locale) {
        // Using a Locale to see the differences between regions.
        DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat (format, otherSymbols);

        // Create the String result
        String output = formatter.format(number);

        // Format the output for a nice presentation.
        System.out.format("    %s %20s %11s = %20s\n", locale, number, format, output);
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
====== ZERO =================================================
en_US                  0.0         #.# =                    0
en_US                  0.0         0.# =                    0
en_US                  0.0         #.0 =                   .0
en_US                  0.0         0.0 =                  0.0
en_US                  0.0        ##.# =                    0
en_US                  0.0        00.# =                   00
====== TEN  =================================================
en_US                 10.0         #.# =                   10
en_US                 10.0         0.# =                   10
en_US                 10.0         #.0 =                 10.0
en_US                 10.0         0.0 =                 10.0
en_US                 10.0        ##.# =                   10
en_US                 10.0        00.# =                   10
====== PI   =================================================
en_US    3.141592653589793         #.# =                  3.1
en_US    3.141592653589793         0.# =                  3.1
en_US    3.141592653589793         #.0 =                  3.1
en_US    3.141592653589793         0.0 =                  3.1
en_US    3.141592653589793        ##.# =                  3.1
en_US    3.141592653589793        00.# =                 03.1
====== MILLIONS =============================================
en_US    2718281.828459045 ###,###.### =        2,718,281.828
de_DE    2718281.828459045 ###,###.### =        2.718.281,828
fr_FR    2718281.828459045 ###,###.### =        2 718 281,828
nl_BE    2718281.828459045 ###,###.### =        2.718.281,828
====== NINERS   =============================================
en_US        9999999.99999         #.# =             10000000
en_US        9999999.99999         0.# =             10000000
en_US        9999999.99999         #.0 =           10000000.0
en_US        9999999.99999         0.0 =           10000000.0
en_US        9999999.99999        ##.# =             10000000
en_US        9999999.99999        00.# =             10000000
en_US        9999999.99999 #.######### =        9999999.99999
=============================================================
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
int count = 10;
int total = 20;
int another=0;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

System.out.println(df.format(count));
System.out.println(df.format(total ));
System.out.println(df.format(another));
```

The output is:
10.00
20.00
0.00

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DecimalFormat of "0.00" instead.  According to the [JavaDocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), this won't strip off the extra 0s.

Comment: it's still stripping off an extra zero with the "0.00" format :(

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

with

```
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```