# Android Java Decimal Format - Zero is hidden after decimal point

Tags: java, android, zero, decimalformat, decimal-point

In my app, i want to be able to format numbers to string (with commas) in a TextView e.g 123456.000 to 123,456.000. But the problem is when i type zero (0) as the last number after the decimal point, it shows nothing until i type another number. For example, if i type 123456.000, i get 123,456. The zeros doesn't show until i type another number like "1" then i get 123,456.0001. Please how do i make zeros show as last number after decimal point? Below are some sample codes.

I apologise for the clumsiness of the code. I manually typed it with my phone.

```
TextView txtView;
boolean NumberClicked = false;
String number = "";

// format pattern
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#########");


// input dot (decimal point)
dot.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickLstener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
if    (!txtView.getText.toString.contains(".") {
input(".");}}});

// input zero (0)
zero.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickLstener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
input("0");
}});

// input one (1)
one.setOnClickListener (new 
View.OnClickLstener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
input("1");}});

// input method
public void input (String view) {
if (!numberClicked) {
number = view;
numberClicked = true;
} else {
number = number + view;
}
// print the entered numbers to
//the TextView after formatting 
if (!number.endsWith(".")) { txtView.setText(formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(number)));}}
```

enter code here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show padding zeros using DecimalFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739734/show-padding-zeros-using-decimalformat)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code snippet:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0#");
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
String value = df.format(123456.000);
```

> **Output: 123,456.000**

For more info pls [click here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat)

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
String.format("%,.03f", 123456.000)
```