# How can I format double with left zero pads?

Tags: java, printf

I have a `double` value between `.0d`(inclusive) and `60.0d`(exclusive).

How can I format the value with left zero padded?

for instance,

- `0.1234567` -> `00.1234567`
- `5.12345678` -> `05.12345678`
- `31.123456789` -> `31.123456789`
- `59.0000000001....` -> `59.0000000001....`

Comment: Use the [Class Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: @K.Nicholas Thank you for your comment. Can you please give me an example? Say printing `5.12345678` into `05.12345678`?

Comment: I'll pass on that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740581/2638227

Answer (score 3):

Use the *[DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)* class.

```java
double[] a = { 0.1234567, 5.12345678, 31.123456789 };
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat();
f.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
f.setMaximumFractionDigits(20);
for (double v : a) System.out.println(f.format(v));
```

Output

```
00.1234567
05.12345678
31.123456789
```

Comment: Do we have any defined constant for the `20` fraction digits? Thanks.

Comment: @JinKwon, I believe it's 16 decimal digits.  _"... decimal formats are described, matching the lengths of the 32–128-bit binary formats. These give decimal interchange formats with 7, 16, and 34-digit significands ..."_, from, _[Wikipedia – IEEE 754-2008 revision – Clause_3: Formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008_revision#Clause_3:_Formats)_.

Comment: Forgive me @Reilas. So, the `20` or `16`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with `String.format()`:

```java
double num = 5.12345678;
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "%f", num));      // 5.123457
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "%.4f", num));    // 5.1235
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "%7.4f", num));   //  5.1235
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "%07.4f", num));  // 05.1235
```

Comment: `%.f` discards some digits as you can see. I need to know how to print with an optional left-padded zero and all decimal digits.

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently solving my problem with the following logic.

```java
double d = ...
var f = d % 1;
var i = d - f;
var formatted = String.format("%1$02d", i) + 
                BigDecimal.valueOf(f).toString().substring(1);
```